# Is there a langchain document loader that loads data directly from an API?

Tags: openai-api, embedding, langchain, py-langchain

I am working with Langchain(python) and OpenAI. I have been testing different document loaders in Langchain. Recently I used SitemapLoader to query a website.

> from langchain.document_loaders.sitemap import SitemapLoader
>
> loader = SitemapLoader(
> "https://ind.nl/sitemap.xml",
> filter_urls=["https://ind.nl/en"] )

This approach works well when I want to use a website's sitemap for embedding text.

Now, I need to work with a database hosted elsewhere that is only accessible through an API. After extensive research, I've realized that I can pull data from the API endpoint and temporarily store it before making its embeddings. However, this may not be a practical solution if the dataset is too large, as it would consume a lot of storage even if it's temporary.

I'm relatively new to programming, and I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Do you have any suggestions for a more efficient approach? If you could provide links to articles or resources that could help in my case, it would be immensely helpful. Thank you.